Need help with 220v Spa Disconnect
I acquired a spa that runs on 220v.  The manual states that for my model I need the following:

Your 220-volt spa pack will require a 40-amp dedicated G.F.C.I. circuit breaker.
Never tie ground and neutral together.
The minimum conductor ampacity for your 220-volt system is 38-amps.
The maximum over current protection device for your 220-volt system is 40-amps.

Breaker         220v
CAPACITY     40 amps
POLES               2
WIRES               4
I’m having difficulty finding a 40 amp GFCI outside disconnect for the spa.  They seem to come mostly in 50 or 60 amp.  MY QUESTION: I am wondering if I can use a 50 or 60 amp GFCI outside disconnect instead of a 40.  My plan was to use 8-gauge wire and to install a 40 amp double breaker on my main electric panel.  Thanks for any help.



Do you have any outlets in the vicinity of the spa?  If not, you should consider a 60A circuit out to the spa location, a small 60A subpanel there that will act as a disconnect for the spa and also provide an outlet or two for lights, music, phone chargers, and if you need it, you can plug in your power washer etc there too.

Are you in Europe? Nothing is 220V in North America. If your manual actually mentions 220 it must be from elsewhere.

@isherwood And yet 230V in Europe isn't split-phase so you wouldn't have the "two hots and a neutral" situation seen here, you'd just have a hot and a neutral (and a ground). There's a few smaller countries that seem to do 110/220 split-phase (Taiwan? Belize?) but they're not likely to use torque ratings in in-lbs. While it's not the nominal voltage, calling it 110/220 does not seem unheard of in America.

That works
Since your circuit is protected by the 40A breaker in the panel, the "spa box" GFCI can be bigger if you want it to be as it doesn't need to provide overcurrent protection to the spa, just GFCI protection.

Thank you for your reply. I did a little more research and it looks like I would not be able to use 8 gauge wire if the spa box was either 50 or 60 amps.  Below is what I found as far as amps & wire gauge requirements.
15 amps 14 gauge wire,
20 amps 12 gauge wire,
30 amps 10 gauge wire,
40 amps 8 gauge wire,
50 amps 6 gauge wire,
60 amps 4 gauge wire.
If this is correct then it seems I would have to have a 40 amp spa box if I were to use 8 gauge copper wire throughout both lines.

I have this exact setup: 8 gauge wire, 40A breaker in the panel, 50A breaker in the disconnect box.

You could also add a 40A GFCI breaker in your main panel and run your #8 AWG wire to an outside straight disconnect switch. This way, you only need one breaker. If your spa only uses 240V, no 120V, you won't need the neutral going from the breaker to the disconnect/spa.

Thanks for your reply. So, from what you’re saying the GFCI function can be anywhere in the line & doesn’t necessarily have to be in the outside box.  Can tell me more about the “outside straight disconnect switch”?  Is this one of those boxes with an on/off pull down lever or simply a regular 40 amp breaker inside the outside box?  Also, I added a second picture in my original posting showing the spa panel.  There’s slots for 2 hot wires, a common & a ground.  Wouldn’t I still need a ground wire?  I don’t think including a ground wire would require much as I could just add a 12 gauge wire.

That is how our spa is wired.

@JACK  I agree with you, except the outside disconnect is minimum 40A (was 30A a typo?).

@DonL Yes, the GFCI breaker can be installed in the main panel. It doesn't have to be outside. The outside disconnect is a 60A, pull out switch, commonly referred to as an AC disconnect switch. It has a plastic handle that just pulls straight out and has two copper "jumpers" that make or break both poles. ... about 17 bucks at your home store. Instructions say 4 wire so you'll need a ground and also a neutral.

@Technophile  Typo, thanks.

Yes, you can do that.
The other option is to use install a small subpanel near the spa, with a 40A GFCI breaker for the spa. If you feed the subpanel with a larger circuit (8 AWG copper wires in conduit (not cable) and 50A, 6 AWG copper cable and 60A, 6 AWG copper wires in conduit and 60A, 6 AWG aluminum wires and 50A) then you can have additional circuits in the subpanel for lights and receptacles.
